# Password hashes differ in development and live server

Tags: php

I just installed xampp, so i can test my website offline.  Now i get numerous Undefined index or Undefined variable errors, which i know how to fix.   Now logging in works online but with xampp it doesn't work.  The code isn't wrong.  I imported the database online to offline. I've pin pointed what is wrong but don't know how to solve it.

here is the code where i test if the login details are correct.

```
$Blowfish_Pre = '$2a$05$';
$Blowfish_End = '$';
$hashed_password = crypt($password, $Blowfish_Pre . $salt . $Blowfish_End);

//check to see if they match
if ($username==$dbusername&&$hashed_password==$dbpassword){
```

Offline the echoed `$hashed_password` for the account is `$2a$05$CEDaiUETMOTuZ1tzSX1dW.1rmbYfiu1Hf6jnZyJ5DouQOIHEPwXiW`

Online the echoed `$hashed_password` for the account is

```
$2J7rPSsTYb1Q
```

I've determined crypt is working differently online then it is offline?  Why is this and how can i solve it?

Comment: `var_dump(CRYPT_BLOWFISH)` to see if your system supports blowfish.

Comment: what is `var_dump(array($password, $Blowfish_Pre, $salt, $Blowfish_End))` on and offline?

Comment: compare the php versions, there have been some changes since php 5.3.

Comment: online var_dump(CRYPT_BLOWFISH) is `int(0)` and offline it is `int(1)`

Comment: So your online passwords are not actually getting hashed with blowfish but with a fallback algorithm...

Comment: online my php version is 5.2.17 ... and offline my php version is 5.4.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`crypt()` uses different hash algorithm depending on what the system provides. Starting with PHP 5.3 it "contains its own implementation and will use that if the system lacks of support for one or more of the algorithms."

Your offline version does use blowfish as you can see at the start `$2a$`. Your online version does use some fallback.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: so i have to match php versions online and offline?

Comment: @user892134 more likely you'll have to use a hash that is supported by both versions.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment..yet, so I place this answer in hope I can save some people some time. 
I had the same question asked, and the chosen answer led me to the solution. But since it did not provide my ultimate solution, I thought I would share to save someone time.

My wamserver was PHP 5.38
my production server I found out was 5.2x
I simply asked them to upgrade me to the latest version, which was 5.4.22...and that solved the issue. The same code started kicking out 60 character hashes again.

So I would bet that if you have this same occurrence, upgrade the server acting up to the latest version of PHP or something over 5.3 and you should be good.